# Convert bytes to long in python

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes, endianness

Here is my C++ code:

```
  int r; // result of log_2(v) goes here
  union { unsigned int u[2]; double d; } t; // temp

  t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] = 0x43300000;
  t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER!=LITTLE_ENDIAN] = v;
  t.d -= 4503599627370496.0;
  r = (t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] >> 20) - 0x3FF;
  return r;
```

I am trying to replicate this piece code exactly in python and so far my code is :

```
class s(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("u", c_ulonglong), ("d", c_double)]
  t = s()
  t.u = pack('<Q', c_ulonglong(int("0x43300000", 16))) # Error cannot convert argument to integer
  t.u = pack('>Q', c_ulonglong(v))
  t.d -= 4503599627370496.0
  r = (t.u >> 20) - 0x3FF
```

I am getting an error while packing the hex number into "u" the way it is mentioned in the c++ code. I would like to solve this error and successfully complete this code in python.

Comment: Your C++ code is not legal to begin with. You cannot read a `union` member other than the one last assigned to.

Comment: Where is the C++ in this C code?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ok i will change the union into a struct but that does not still solve my problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAliQadri Changing `union` to `struct` will change the meaning of the code and make it even more nonsensical.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I understand my mistake in using a struct and that changes the meaning of the code. But moving on I still need to fix the error i am facing while using the pack function.

Comment: "*I am getting an error*" - care to tell us what the error message is?

Comment: @cdarke i have commented the error message in the python code in front of the line **t.u = pack('<Q', c_ulonglong(int("0x43300000", 16)))**

Comment: That is coming from `struct.pack()`, it can't handle a c_ulonglong object.  This might be of interest:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/ctypes

Answer (score 0):

It helps to have a complete example (lots of undefined values here), but this is closer to the intent.  Note the use of `Union` and `c_int * 2`:

```
class s(Union):
    _fields_ = [("u", c_int * 2),
                ("d", c_double)]

t = s()
t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] = 0x43300000
t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER!=LITTLE_ENDIAN] = v # whatever that is
t.d -= 4503599627370496.0
r = (t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] >> 20) - 0x3FF
return r
```